# Error when executing script in sqlplus, option not a valid number

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to execute this command in sqlplus, I've tried putting it in a
.sql file, and .txt file also.

```
set linesize 400;
set pages 999; 
spool odi_query.txt 
declare 
v_extract_date DATE; 
begin 
select extract_date into v_extract_date
from LORIK_UNIT.Toad_zhurnal; 
LORIK_UNIT.lorik_utils.p_create_daily_partitions (v_extract_date ); 
end; 
/ 
spool off
```

This is the error which I received after executing it:

```
SP2-0268: linesize option not a valid number
SP2-0268: pagesize option not a valid number
```

Does anyone know what might be the cause of it?

Comment: This works OK for me. Please, copy/paste the **whole** SQL*Plus session so that we could see what exactly you did and how Oracle responded. Apart from that, unless table toad_zhurnal contains one row, that select will raise TOO_MANY_ROWS (or, possibly, NO_DATA_FOUND error).

Comment: This might be one of the very rare cases where a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Might also want to check that your line endings match the environment where you're running it (unix/windows).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this code had extra spaces after each line, by removing those, now it executes smoothly.

```
set linesize 400
set pages 999

spool odi_query.txt

declare
v_extract_date DATE;
begin

select extract_date into v_extract_date
from LORIK_UNIT.Toad_zhurnal;

LORIK_UNIT.lorik_utils.p_create_daily_partitions (v_extract_date );
end;
/
spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolons `;` at the end of the lines.

Comment: Ok... Then, still the error message should provide hints.  if semicolon removal does not help, then  your code should have some other hidden characters which are parsed as part of the parameter, i.e. e.g. control characters, as @kfinity pointed out. And as other people say, for better investigation, please provide the whole operation you did.

Comment: It is working fine now, I checked empty spaces and it seemed to have a space after each line. After removing those spaces, procedure is successfully completed.